# javascript syntax for regex using variable as pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable patt with a dynamic numerical value

```
var patt = "%"+number+":";
```

What is the regex syntax for using it in the test() method?

I have been using this format

```
var patt=/testing/g;
var found = patt.test(textinput);
```

TIA

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yeah, you pretty much had it. You just needed to pass your regex string into the RegExp constructor. You can then call its `test()` function.

```
var matcher = new RegExp("%" + number + ":", "g");
var found = matcher.test(textinput);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Be careful when you want to use a special character that is also a string escape character like, `\s`, you will need to double-escape some special characters, Eg: `new RegExp(\`\\s*${var}\`, 'g')` to match all whitespace up to a variable.

Answer (score 8):

You have to build the regex using a regex object, rather than the regex literal.

From your question, I'm not exactly sure what your matching criteria is, but if you want to match the number along with the '%' and ':' markers, you'd do something like the following:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("%" + num_to_match + ":", "g");
```

You can read up more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track

```
var testVar = '%3:';

var num = 3;

var patt = '%' + num + ':';

var result = patt.match(testVar);

alert(result);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ygfQ8/2/

You should not use `number`.  Although it is not a reserved word, it is one of the predefined class/object names.

And your pattern is fine without turning it into a regex literal.

Comment: Your example works because you have MooTools loaded. A String doesn't normally have a `.test()` method. And `number` is not a reserved word.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ  You're so right!!  Thinking in frameworks too much.  I've edited to remove `test()` for `match()`.  Thanks for the catch.  Also, you're right about `number` not being a reserved word.  Edited that too to be more clear.  Typing to quickly without double-checking my facts. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

These days many people enjoy ES6 syntax with babel. If this is your case then there is an option without string concatenation:

```
const matcher = new RegExp(`%${num_to_match}:`, "g");
```